# I want to add the values of 2 UILabels together to display the results in a separate UILabel

Tags: ios, swift

```
//un-wrap string in label and cast to Int

let made = ShotsMadeLabel.text?.toInt()  //shots made Int 
let miss = ShotsMissedLabel.text?.toInt() //shots missed Int

// check to see if both values are not equal to zero       
//  add values and display answer (ans)in TotshotShotsMadelabel

if (miss != 0) || (made != 0){
var ans = made! + miss!
TotalShotsMadeLabel.text =  "\(ans)"

println(ans) // check results
```

> per request provided clarity to my question.. please let me know if there is a better way to do this..

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @matt, is there another way to to display the results with out using a UILabel?

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks good but it fails to cover the case where one of the labels' text is empty or not a number. In that case, `made` or `miss` can be nil and you will crash when you force-unwrap it (with the exclamation mark).

So, you'd need to add another level of safety:

```
if (miss != 0) || (made != 0) {
    if (miss != nil) && (made != nil) {
        var ans = made! + miss!
    }
}
```

But the truth is that you should not be doing this in the first place. Do *not* store state in a view like a label! This whole business of extracting the text from a label and turning it into a number is just wrong. You should have model *variables* in your *code* that are actual numbers, maintaining this information. When they change, change the labels. And that way, you can just add them. MVC, model-view-controller. Do not use View as Model, which is what you are doing.

Comment: And for more lecturing about that, see my book: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch13.html#_model_view_controller